# How can I create a horizontal bargraph with x= type float and y= type object

Tags: python, pandas

Data has >400 rows, This is a sample:

```
TIME    PERSON
0   22.222222   Runner
1   23.796791   Cyclist
2   20.789474   Swimmer
3   21.270718   Pedestrain
4   19.518717   Kid
```

time is type:float Person is type:Object

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

raw_data = pd.DataFrame({"PERSON": ['PERSON']})


plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
raw_data.plot(kind='barh', x=raw_data['TIME'], y="PERSON")
plt.xlabel("TIME")
plt.ylabel("PERSON")

plt.show()
```

Not sure how to categorize "PERSON" as it has multiple different types, do I have to name one by one? I'd like to group values in 'PERSON' and show average for 'TIME'. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use seaborn library, which you already has included in your code. It's developed to do such graphs "from the box":

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10))
sns.barplot(x='TIME', y='PERSON', data=raw_data)
```

And for grouping by PERSON and averaging by TIME answer is this simple:

```
sns.barplot(x='TIME', y='PERSON', data=raw_data.groupby('PERSON').mean().reset_index())
```

Comment: I just tried both and it says  TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: @ruben.lfdz have you constructed your DataFrame like this: raw_data = pd.DataFrame({"PERSON": ['Runner','Cyclist','Runner'], 'TIME': [22.222222, 23.796791, 23.796791]}) ?

Comment: no I've called it from a .csv Thats why I was asking how to categorize the data as I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: raw_data = pd.DataFrame({"PERSON": [raw_data['PERSON']]})

Comment: That's how I tried

Comment: @ruben.lfdz First of all: don't call different python objects by the same name, you will be very confused. And you don't need this string of code, you already have a good DataFrame, I think, but by this string you are making Series from DataFrame. Then you will get this error because you are working with Series as with DataFrame.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, so how can I do it ?

Comment: You need both columns PERSON and TIME for your DataFrame, but you are taking only PERSON column by this string. And you placing it in the variable with the same name as initial DataFrame.

Comment: What was in raw_data before this code: raw_data = pd.DataFrame({"PERSON": [raw_data['PERSON']]})? Was it DataFrame already, can you use it with my code? What's what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes It was a DataFrame already type object, I can't use it with you code TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: Show me raw_data.info() please. And raw_data.head()

Comment: And try to give different names to DataFrame you read from csv and to DataFrame you are trying to plot. It's a mess because you have two different DataFrames with a same name.

Comment: Your DataFrame have to have at list two columns: TIME and PERSON to plot it my way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206298/discussion-between-ruben-lfdz-and-crazyelf).